# Fotorama navigation in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, fotorama

I'm using the Fotorama image script on my website. I have data-allowfullscreen="native".  When I go into full screen in Firefox, the navigation and return from full-screen buttons sometimes disappear.  If I click on either the right or left of the image, I can go forward or back.  To exit full screen I have to press the Esc key.  The issue only appears to be with Firefox.  I put the code for my page below.

```
<td width="1008"><div class="fotorama" data-width="950" data-max-width="100%" data-max-height="97%" data-allowfullscreen="native"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-1.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-2-3.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-4-5.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-6-7.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-8-9.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-10-11.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-12-13.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-14-15.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-16-17.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-18-19.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-20-21.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-22-23.jpg"> 
<img src="../../images/1979/02/1979-02-24.jpg"></div></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you confusing the attributes? 
just remove the "-"

```
<div class="fotorama" data-width="950" data-maxwidth="100%" data-maxheight="97%" data-allowfullscreen="native">
```

[fotorama.io](http://fotorama.io/customize/dimensions/)